Pandas can't convert to JSON
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(job_title, company, location, pay)),
                  columns=['Job Title', 'Company', 
                  'Location', 'Payment'])
    
    
df.to_json('Job_Thai.json', orient='records', force_ascii=False,
           lines=True, mode='a')

I tried to convert this Dataframe to a JSON file. The program runs normally but for some reason the JSON file doesn't appear.
I tried changing orient, lines and mode. Nothing seems to work. If anyone knows what might be the cause of this, would you let me know?

You used a relative path. Are you sure you're looking in the correct folder? I can't reproduce this using even an empty dataframe.

This question is similar to: What's the working directory when using IDLE?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If your "program run[s] normally", then the file will have been created in your working directory. Check os.getcwd(). For future reference, always create a [mre]. The code provided cannot be run by users as it contains undefined variables (e.g. job_title).

Related: open() gives FileNotFoundError / IOError: '[Errno 2] No such file or directory' (about reading a relative path)

If Pandas actually couldn't convert to JSON, you'd get an error (an exception).

BTW, if no one's said it before, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

pls include how your csv looks like or how you expecting the json the to look like. It's hard to predict where things going wrong without minimal code

check out from where you are running the script. As using relative path, if there's no exception, most probably you have the file in the same directory as the execution path
